# string[] is not assignable to type string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I am trying to learn typescript. emphasis on trying.

But the following code gives me an error of **string[] is not assignable to type string**
It gives me the error on the values in between <TodoContext.Provider value={[todos, setotodos]>

Thanks for your help!

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

export const TodoContext = createContext<string[]>([]);

export function TodoComponent({ children }: Props) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<string[] | never>([]);
  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={[todos, setTodos]}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default TodoComponent;
```

Comment: You're trying to shove an array into a property that isn't an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createContext<string[]>([]);
```

This means that the value will be an array of strings. So for example, you could safely do the following, since todos is an array of strings:

```
<TodoContext.Provider value={todos}>
```

But what you're trying to pass in is `value={[todos, setTodos]}`. That's an array that contains a string array, and a function. Assuming you want the type information to preserve the order (that index 0 is the string array, and index 1 is the function), you'll do that with a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like this:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

createContext<[string[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>]([[], () => {}])
```

`Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>` Is the types that react provides for the state setter function. If you wanted to create that type yourself it would be:

```
(string[] | ((prevState: string[]) => string[])) => void
```

In other words, a function that you can either pass a string array into, or you can pass a function into it which will get the previous state and return the new state

---

P.S, the `never` in this type has no effect:

```
useState<string[] | never>([]);
```

It can just be:

```
useState<string[]>([]);
```